# Google streetview javascript api displaying gray screen as of 1 nov 2018

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, twebbrowser

The following sample code from google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed no longer seems to work in our desktop application.

In fact it's giving us a gray screen, but with all the interface markers still in tact: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqW7F.jpg - and plenty of warnings (which javascript/css can hide, so not worried about those.) see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvEJv.jpg (for the working split view, but the same gray streetview)

This has been happening since about 1 nov 2018. I'm not sure what changed,. I'm not finding similar questions (except way older ones which appear unrelated).

I was curious if anyone else has seen the problem we are running into currently - or whether there's an alternative method for implementing the google api that i'm not aware of yet - or perhaps google has implemented some restrictions for implementing their api that have recently been added.

Update: Internally it's using a delphi TWebBrowser component, which seems to be using IE-9 or earlier. When browsing google's demo code on IE, and setting emulation to IE-9, i'm getting the exact same gray background that i'm seeing in the software. It would seem that google stopped IE-9 support as of the first this month?

Comment: What did you do on 1st Nov. 2018? This looks like a CSS issue. Check what applies to images globally in your website or specifically on the map container element. In any case, the code you shared can **not** be used to reproduce the problem (you saw that by yourself as both the example and codepen work).

Comment: Absolutely nothing I fear. Medio October we rolled out the new split view as seen in the screenshot and it was working perfectly. I even dragged up the old html/css/js from the start of this year - and it's displaying the same gray screen. So I'm 100% sure it's not anything we changed code wise.
The logical conclusion from my point of view would be that google changed something - but i'm not finding any major changes that would seem to be related to this for the last few weeks / month. The google api key requirement isn't the cause either - since that results in a monochrome view.

Comment: I am 100% sure the issue comes from **your** code. But you still **didn't share any code** that allows to reproduce the issue. Again, this looks like **a CSS issue**. Did you check your CSS? If you need anyone to look into this, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code is in the first link - google's demo. That's the exact code that we're showing. :)
I can't extract the win32 application / dll into a separate project - it's,. too complicated I fear.    Basically it's a delphi program starting a TWebBrowser component which pops up the google code,. nothing fancy - always worked, and still works, with exception to 1 tiny part of the google streetview view. :/

HA,. actually that does seem to be the core of the issue - IE-9 doesn't work with streetview anymore. and the twebbrowser uses IE at it's core. Seems google stopped streetview support for IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found,. the problem was indeed in the TWebBrowser using IE9 compatibility mode (which google no longer seems to support). By default it was actually running 7, but we already fixed a similar issue before and had it set to 9.

The solution is to set compatibility mode to IE11, and suddenly it works perfectly again.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/19bdbd98-83a3-4787-8d85-7f2d6f0446f9/featurebrowseremulation-code-for-ie11?forum=iewebdevelopment

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n11AB.jpg